# jQuery cant work with iFrame src

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe, attributes

i have problem that jQuery didnt show up iframe. i have many iframe in my website. when u click link to show up in iframe. but it doesnt show. here my code:

```
//i load plugin: 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function godirect(url, num)
{
    var target = 'iframe_url' + num;

    var source = jQuery(target).attr('src');

    if (source == "about:blank" || source == "")
    {
        jQuery(target).attr('src', url);
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(target).attr('src', 'about:blank');
    }

}
</script>
```

PHP & HTML code:

```
$godirect = 'godirect(&quot;'.$GetData['link'].'&quot;, &quot;'.$a.'&quot;);';

<a href="#" <?php echo $godirect; ?> > TEST LINK </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code instead, assuming `target` is the ID of the frame element:

```
var target = 'iframe_url' + num;
var oFrame = $("#" + target);
var source = oFrame.attr('src');
if (source == "about:blank" || source == "")
{
    oFrame.attr('src', url);
}
else
{
    oFrame.attr('src', 'about:blank');
}
```

Edit: when initially empty, the `src` attribute might be null so try this:

```
if (source == "about:blank" || source == "" || source == null)
```

Comment: it works with oFrame but its problem with IF & ELSE. i feel it cant get value of attribute 'src'. i tried test without IF & ELSE it was work. but with IF & ELSE is not work.

Comment: i found problem... i need to add one more: "source == null" in IF. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the godirect call in the href-attribute or the onclick-attribute of the anchor. Currently your output looks like this:

```
<a href="#" godirect("url", "num");>TEST LINK</a>
```

and should be:

```
<a href="javascript:godirect("url", "num");">TEST LINK</a>
```

Comment: sorry. i tried that but i believe the problem with IF & ELSE in jQuery. thanks, erik.